# Is Java 8 Stream a safe return type?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Are Java 8 Streams safe return types for public methods, in that it would be impossible to mutate the underlying object given a stream from it?

For example, if I have a `List` and `return list.stream();` could the return value in any way be used to mutate the original list?

Judging from the API, I don't think it's possible but would like to confirm.

Comment: Read the following and you'll get a good notion of why streams will not modify the source (a collection in your example): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Comment: Getting a stream from the list should not modify the data structure "itself" but it can modify its content if it contains mutable objects. But this principle is about data-structures in general anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to do so. Streams do not/should not modify the underlying data structure.

A few excerpts from [`java.util.stream.Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A *sequence* of elements […].
>
> Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities, have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast, **streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their elements** […].
>
> To preserve correct behavior, [behavioral parameters to stream operations …] must be non-interfering (they do not modify the stream source).

And from [*Package `java.util.stream` Description*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description):

> Streams differ from collections in several ways:
>
> - No storage. **A stream is not a data structure that stores elements**; instead, it conveys elements from a source […], through a pipeline of computational operations.
> - Functional in nature. **An operation on a stream produces a result, but does not modify its source.**

You might also see [*Non-interference*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference).

---

> […] it would be *impossible* to mutate the underlying object given a stream from it.

While it would be *possible* to write our *own* implementation of `java.util.Stream` that modified the underlying data structure, it would be an error to do so. ; )

---

In response to the comment by @AlexisC.:

> Getting a stream from the list […] can modify its *content* if it contains mutable objects.

This is a fair point. If we have a stream of *elements which are mutable*, we can do:

```
myObj.stream().forEach(( Foo foo ) -> ( foo.bar = baz ));
```

Comment: Except for reflection of course. I didn't try it but I would be very surprised if you couldn't use reflection to access and modify the underlying structure of the stream.

Comment: Just to clarify, the collection itself cannot be modified by a stream, but the items can if they are mutable. If you do not want the items themselves modified, make them immutable via final and encapsulation.

Comment: @kajacx It would be possible to obtain a reference to the underlying data structure with reflection but the same could be said for any immutability in Java. Nothing is immutable if you want to write some hacky code. Same applies to e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

Comment: Another aspect of Stream vs. List is the point in time that its elements are actually created. Due to the fact that a Stream is executed lazily, the caller implicitly decides when that happens. Depending on when the caller processes the Stream, the result may differ. (if the elements can vary over time) Whereas a List epresents a _snapshot_ that the returning method takes when invoked.